# A simple question on the CR equations

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Given $f(z)=x^2+iy^2$ I need to find where this function is differentiable. According to the Cauchy Riemann equations, we have 
$$u_x=2x=v_y=2y,\quad u_y=0=-v_x=0.$$

So would this function be differentiable only at $P(0,0)$ or $x=y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But that togeher with the fact that the partial derivatives are continuous is enough for that.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that. So is it only at the point $(0,0)$?

Comment: @MathGuru Yes, that's it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos are you sure the function is differentiable only at the origin?

Comment: @Denis28 No. Thank you for calling my attention to that. It is differentiable at all the poits of the form $x+xi$ ($x\in\mathbb R$) and only at those points.